# having error with the .map function in the code of mine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

read.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: APIData.map is not a function. I am facing this error when I changed the existing API which was a need to do and even there is one more problem I am facing other than this error is that in my registration form my the entered data is taking data but it is not stored in the database so there is a problem.

```
at Read (read.js:73:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

create.js(registration form code)

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
    
    export default function Create() {
        let navigate = useNavigate();
        const [Employee_name, setEmployee_name] = useState('');
        const [Employee_id, setEmployee_id] = useState('');
        const [Employee_address, setEmployee_address] = useState('');
        const [Employee_post, setEmployee_post] = useState('');
        const [username, setusername] = useState('');
        const [Employee_password, setEmployee_password] = useState('');
    
        const postData = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            if (Employee_name, Employee_id, Employee_address, Employee_post, username, Employee_password.length === 0) {
                alert('Enter Employee Details to register!')
                return false
            }
    
            if (Employee_name.length === 0) {
                alert('Enter Employee Name!')
                return false
            }
            if (Employee_id.length === 0) {
                alert('Enter Employee id!')
                return false
            }
            if (Employee_address.length === 0) {
                alert('Enter Employee address!')
                return false
            }
            if (Employee_post.length === 0) {
                alert('Enter Employee Position!')
                return false
            }
            if (username.length === 0) {
                alert('Set Employee Username!')
                return false
            }
            if (Employee_password.length === 0) {
                alert('Set Employee Password!')
                return false
            }
    
            axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/users/`, {
                Employee_name,
                Employee_id,
                Employee_address,
                Employee_post,
                username,
                Employee_password
    
            })
                .then(() => {
                    navigate('/Login')
                })
    
            alert('Data Saved')
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Form className="create-form" onSubmit={e => postData(e)}>
                    <h2 className='Header'>Employee Registration form</h2>
                    <Form.Field required={true}>
                        <label>Employee Name</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Name' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_name(e.target.value)} />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field required={true}>
                        <label>Employee ID</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Employee ID' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_id(e.target.value)} />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field required={true}>
                        <label>Employee Address</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Address' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_address(e.target.value)} />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field required={true}>
                        <label>Employee Position</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Position' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_post(e.target.value)} />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field required={true}>
                        <label>Create Username</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Username' onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)} />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field required={true}>
                        <label>Create Password</label>
                        <input type='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_password(e.target.value)} />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Button className='b2' onClick={postData} type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

read.js(the error 'read.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: APIData.map is not a function')

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    export default function Read() {
        let navigate = useNavigate();
    
        const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/users/`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    setAPIData(response.data);
                })
        }, []);
    
        const setData = (data) => {
            let { Employee_name, Employee_id, Employee_address, Employee_post, username, Employee_password } = data;
    
            localStorage.setItem('Employee ID', Employee_id);
    
            navigate('/update')
        }
    
        const getData = () => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/users/`)
                .then((getData) => {
                    setAPIData(getData.data);
                })
        }
    
        const onDelete = (data) => {
    
            const { Employee_id } = data
            if (Employee_id === 0) {
                alert("Employee id not found")
                return
            }
            const url = `http://localhost:4000/api/users/${Employee_id}`
            axios.delete(url)
                .then((res) => {
                    getData();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
            alert('Employee Deleted!')
        }
    
    
        const Data = () => {
            navigate('/login')
        }
    
        return (
            <form>
                <h2>Registered Employees</h2>
                <div>
                    <Table singleLine>
                        <Table.Header>
                            <Table.Row>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Employee ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Position</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Username</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Password</Table.HeaderCell>
    
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Delete</Table.HeaderCell>
                            </Table.Row>
                        </Table.Header>
    
                        <Table.Body>
                            {APIData.map((data, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <Table.Row key={index + ""}>
                                        <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_name}</Table.Cell>
                                        <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_id}</Table.Cell>
                                        <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_address}</Table.Cell>
                                        <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_post}</Table.Cell>
                                        <Table.Cell>{data.username}</Table.Cell>
                                        <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_password}</Table.Cell>
    
                                        {/* <Link to='/update'> */}
                                        <Table.Cell>
                                            <Button onClick={() => setData(data)}>Update</Button>
                                        </Table.Cell>
                                        {/* </Link> */}
                                        <Table.Cell>
                                            <Button onClick={() => onDelete(data)}>Delete</Button>
                                        </Table.Cell>
                                    </Table.Row>
                                )
                            })}
                        </Table.Body>
                    </Table>
                    <Button onClick={Data} type='submit'>Home</Button>
                </div>
            </form>
    
        )
    }
```

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen there is no `each` in javascript

Comment: Seems like one of your endpoints is returning an object, not an array

Comment: Can you change line 73 on read.js like `{APIData?.map((data, index) => {`?

Comment: what is the return type of the endpoint??

Comment: it is showing error

Comment: can you add console.log(response.data) result to your question?